# error on building cross gcc - "exec -I

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am getting an error on building a cross compile version of GCC:

```
/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/./gcc/xgcc -B/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/./gcc/ -B/usr/l
ocal/i686-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/i6 
86-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/i686-linux-gnu/sys-include    -g -O2 -O
2 -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/../winsup/w32api/include -g -O2 -DIN_GCC
 -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prot
otypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include   -g -DIN
_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector -Dinhibit_libc  -I. -I. -I../../
./gcc -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgc
c/. -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/../gcc -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/
libgcc/../include -I/c/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/config/libbid -DENABLE_D
ECIMAL_BID_FORMAT -DHAVE_CC_TLS -DUSE_EMUTLS -o _chkstk_s.o -MT _chkstk_s.o -MD
-MP -MF _chkstk_s.dep -DSHARED -DL_chkstk -xassembler-with-cpp -c /c/projects/VO
/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/config/i386/cygwin.S
c:/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/gcc/as: line 87: exec: -I: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
make[2]: *** [_chkstk_s.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/i686-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

"as" is a script file. On placing an echo of what the offending statement will execute:

```
will execute: exec -I c:/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/../winsup/w32api/inclu
de -I . -I . -I ../.././gcc -I c:/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc -I c:/project
s/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/ -I c:/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/../gcc -I c:/p
rojects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgcc/../include -I c:/projects/VO/gcc/gcc-4.7.3/libgc
c/config/libbid --32 -o _chkstk_s.o C:\Users\samiam\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKABZ8H.
s
c:/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/gcc/as: line 88: exec: -I: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
make[2]: *** [_chkstk_s.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj/i686-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/projects/VO/gcc/gccobj'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

"exec" is a shell built in. I can't find any reference to "exec" ever having a -I
option, online or by trying it in the shell.

Thank you,

Scott Moore

Comment: Follow up: The start of the exec command paramters, "-I .../include" implies that what occurred is the command verb got elided, most likely "gcc" or a similar command. "as" is a script, and what was being executed was a heavily macro expanded line.

Comment: Turned out to be that the binutils was not installed yet, so (we believe) the script was attempting to execute something from that package.